# Connecting wifi through url

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, wifi, android-wifi

I'm making a website that works for a restaurant and I want customers easily connect to the restaurant's wifi, so is there any way to connect iOS and Android devices to wifi using url?

I'm looking for a URL, for example, you can send emails using the URL: "mailto:example@mail.com"

I checked these solutions, but they didn't work:

https://superuser.com/a/1459233

https://smartjoin.us/rfcs/wifi-url.html

I'm developing with Vue.js. I prefer to make this using HTML but I can use any library to fix this.

I tried these:

```
<a href="wifi://password@ssid"> click to connect wifi </a>

<a href="WIFI:S:ssid;T:WPA;P:password;H:false;"> click to connect wifi </a>
```

Comment: You can create a QR code and display it on the premises.  There are many QR code generators online that do this already.

Comment: @blurfus it only works for IOS?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible.

Comment: anchor tag links will not work.  QR codes are the only method that have any support for this feature as the superuser link posted by OP already describes.  @code I just tried with Android 13 and it worked fine.

Comment: @code as far as I know, it works for most mobiles with recent OSs (android/iOS - not sure for other OSs)

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem related to Vue or JS? Try to get it work with static markup first

Answer (score -2):

Connecting to a Wi-Fi network using just a URL is not supported by standard web technologies. The "mailto" protocol for email and similar URL schemes are specifically defined and supported by the operating systems and applications.

For connecting to a Wi-Fi network, users typically have to manually access the Wi-Fi settings on their devices and enter the network name (SSID) and password. This process cannot be automated through a simple URL.

To make it more convenient for your customers to connect to the restaurant's Wi-Fi, you can consider alternative approaches:

Display the Wi-Fi network name (SSID) and password on a prominent sign or notice within the restaurant premises. This way, customers can manually select the network and enter the password on their devices.

Create a QR code that contains the Wi-Fi network details (SSID and password). Customers can scan the QR code using their devices, which will automatically populate the network information and allow them to connect easily.

You can generate a QR code using online services or libraries specifically designed for this purpose. There are Vue.js libraries available, such as vue-qrcode or vue-qr-generator, that can help you generate QR codes in your Vue.js project.

Here's an example of using the vue-qrcode library to generate a QR code for the Wi-Fi network:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <qrcode :value="wifiNetworkUrl" :size="200" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import QRCode from 'vue-qrcode';

export default {
  components: {
    QRCode,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      wifiNetworkUrl: 'WIFI:S:ssid;T:WPA;P:password;H:false;',
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

In the above example, the wifiNetworkUrl variable contains the Wi-Fi network information in the required format for generating the QR code. The vue-qrcode library is used to display the QR code on the webpage.

By presenting the QR code, customers can conveniently scan it using their devices' camera or a QR code scanner app, and it will automatically populate the network details for easy connection.

Remember to replace 'ssid' and 'password' with the actual network SSID and password of the restaurant's Wi-Fi network.

Comment: Thank you for your message, but that's not my looking for. As you wrote, there's no way for this. I can do the same without using qr-code library, I can use a static qr-code. Think I'm gonna do that.

Comment: All three of your answers, including this one, this month appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: @mrkanet Please be careful accepting answers that didn't work for you.  **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.